# Does Calculate Geometry tool exist in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, calculate-geometry

Does ArcGIS Pro have a Calculate Geometry tool available for use?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, however it has been renamed to "Add Geometry Attributes tool" Esri documentation [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm) provides the overview of the tool.

> Adds new attribute fields to the input features representing the spatial or geometric characteristics and location of each feature, such as length or area and x-, y-, z-, and m-coordinates.

Also, to see which tool are not available in ArcGIS Pro you can check [Tools that are not available in ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/appendices/unavailable-tools.htm).

Answer (score 6):

As indicated by a [GeoNet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/119615) it appears that the Calculate Geometry tool of ArcMap is replaced in ArcGIS Pro by [Add Geometry Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm) which:

> Adds new attribute fields to the input features representing the
>   spatial or geometric characteristics and location of each feature,
>   such as length or area and x-, y-, z-, and m-coordinates.

Comment: It's interesting that they made the name change.

Comment: @whyzar It was more than a name change and I think done so that some tools accessed from the attribute table like Field Calculator and Calculate Geometry could be made single source as Geoprocessing tools (Calculate Field and Add Geometry Attributes).

Answer (score 5):

As other have mentioned, the Add Geometry Attributes tool can be used. Geometry can also be calculated using a standard field calculation, just as in 10.x and earlier:

In the attribute table, click **'Calculate'**. The Geoprocessing tab will open with the Calculate Field tool ready to go. Select the field you're calculating, and then add the appropriate python statement to the expression.

For example, calculating the area of polygon features in hectares, you would use the statement `!shape.area@hectares!`. Calulating the length of features in kilometres, you would use `!shape.length@kilometres!` (be sure to use US spelling in the statement).